# How to use multiple mock jest functions

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

Jest seems to override the first mock function when I write multiple mock functions. Without mocks it will throw an error "useCreateFleetManager is not a function". If I add the first block of mocks it goes away and show "useUsers is not a function". If I add second block it says "useCreateFleetManager" is not a function again.

```js
jest.mock("services/fleet", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useCreateFleetManager: () => Promise.resolve({
    "mutate": jest.fn()
  }),
  useDeleteFleetManager: () => Promise.resolve({
    "mutate": jest.fn()
  })
}));

jest.mock("services/user", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useUsers: () => Promise.resolve({
    "mutate": jest.fn()
  }),
}));
```

I have multiple custom hooks that I need to mock in a file in order to successfully test this component. Is there a way to write or import multiple mocks with jest?

Comment: what does "seems to not allow me to" mean?

Comment: Without mocks it will throw an error "useCreateFleetManager is not a function". If I add the first block of mocks it goes away and show "useUsers is not a function". If I add second block it says "useCreateFleetManager" is not a function again @AndyRay